# Crop a YUV image

Tags: android, image, image-processing, android-camera, javacv

I have camera preview callback. On onPreviewFrame I will get YUV data. By default my image format is NV21. If I am not wrong data[] is YUV format.

1. Let I have a preview of 640*480.How can I crop this YUV to get a byte[] containing 480*480 YUV image.
2. How can I rotate a YUV Image.
3. If this is difficult to archive how can I crop a IplImage.I am using Javacv to encode a video. Bad luck its greenish.
4. Is there any other way to archive that?

Thanks in Advance
Amlan.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming you want a left most 480 pixels of a column while cropping, you could loop over the the image height (480 rows) and just copy the first 480 pixels for the Y plane. For the UV plane, just copy the first 480 pixels from the original UV plane (this would consist of 240 U and 240 V values), looped over half of image height (240 rows).
2. Generate a rotational transformation matrix for the given rotation angle. It will be something like

   ```
   [cos(theta) -sin(theta)
   sin(theta) cos(theta)]
   ```

   Check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for more info on that. Take it's inverse matrix and for every (x, y) pair of the **resultant rotated** empty image, apply that transformation to get the corresponding (x, y) coordinated in the original image. Use nearest-neighbor or bi-linear interpolation to get the final pixel value.